# Combine two querysets from different models into one queryset

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I need to combine two querysets into one queryset (the result can't be a list or other type of object) as when I iterate on the querysets in a template I need to access their relations, which cannot be done from a list or dictionary.

I've tried solutions like union however this is unacceptable as I need access to the relations in the template.

The loop that I need the data structure for looks like the loop below. The two relations on this object are user and aircraft.

```
{% for key in active %}
<tr>
    <td>{{key.user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{key.aircraft.tail_number}}</td>
    <td>{{key.departure_date}}</td>
    <td>{{key.departure_city|title}}</td>
    <td>{{key.arrival_city|title}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Models:

```
class HaveTrip(models.Model):
    # fields are null by default
    departure_date = models.DateField()
    arrival_date = models.DateField()
    departure_time = models.TimeField()
    arrival_time = models.TimeField()
    departure_city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    departure_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    arrival_city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    arrival_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    trip_notes = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    occupied_seats = models.IntegerField()
    extra_seats = models.IntegerField()
    booking_exp = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.User',
        related_name='have_trip',
        unique=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    aircraft = models.ForeignKey(
        'aircraft.Aircraft',
        related_name='trip',
        unique=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class NeedTrip(models.Model):
    # fields are null by default
    departure_date = models.DateTimeField()
    arrival_date = models.DateField()
    departure_time = models.DateTimeField()
    arrival_time = models.DateTimeField()
    departure_city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    departure_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    arrival_city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    arrival_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    trip_notes = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    primary_guest_passenger = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    preferred_category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    seats_max = models.IntegerField()
    seats_min = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.User',
        related_name='need_trip',
        unique=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

One idea is to somehow do a join between the two tables in a way that a queryset is returned however at this point I've been unable to figure out how to do that. I haven't tried raw SQL yet so maybe that's the route?

Comment: Can you show your models? I think that you can use a property of the model, like "related_name". But I need to see your models.

Comment: Nothing stops you from referencing related objects after converting a queryset to list. If your query truly can't be expressed in a single queryset, I'd focus on figuring out why you had problems working with EG a list built from two querysets. Querysets aren't designed to represent instances of more than one model type.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper makes sense but how do you reference related objects from lists? In the above code it's not working whereas it does when the object is a queryset.

Comment: Assuming your list is a list of model instances, EG from converting two querysets to lists and concatenating, it's just dot notation. `[instance.user for instance in (list(NeedTrip.objects.all()) + list(HaveTrip.objects.all()))]` would be a list of user objects, `{% instance.user %}` in a template, etc.

Comment: Also, I haven't reviewed your models closely but the names and repeated fields make me immediately suspect your design should be normalized. Unfortunately I don't really have time at the moment, but there's some "code smell" there IMO.

Comment: Yea the design could be / will be better but I'm still going to need to solve this problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think querysets of different models can be combined. I would just use itertools.

```
from itertools import chain

active = list(chain(queryset1, queryset2))
```